# [jspdf]: custom font added not working on ipad giving following error

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, unicode, jspdf

i have added custom font to jspdf as below :

pdf.addFileToVFS('ArialUnicodeMS.ttf', base64data.replace('data:font/ttf;base64,', ''));
pdf.addFont('ArialUnicodeMS.ttf', fontName, 'normal');
pdf.setFont(fontName);

it is working fine on browser but not on ipad giving error r.metadata.unicode.widths in getcharwidthArray()

version used:
"jspdf": "2.3.1",

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and put your code in code blocks. This will make the question much more readable.